# Aws::S3::Presigner undefined method credentials for nil:NilClass in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-s3

i have use aws-sdk-core gem i am getting error during getting url form aws
following is my code

```
  def initialize(bucket:, region:)
    @bucket = bucket
    client = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: region)
    @signer = Aws::S3::Presigner.new(client: client)
  end

  def sign(key, expires_in: 3600)
    @signer.presigned_url(:get_object, bucket: @bucket, key: key,    expires_in: expires_in)
  end
```

i am getting error

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `credentials' for nil:NilClass:
  aws-sdk-core (2.1.15) lib/aws-sdk-core/signers/v4.rb:24:in `initialize'
  aws-sdk-core (2.1.15) lib/aws-sdk-core/s3/presigner.rb:88:in `block in sign_but_dont_send'
```

If anyone known how get presigned url please lets us known

Thanks

Comment: We get this error sporadically, using IAM roles on EC2 for credentials. I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 9):

The unhelpful error message indicates that you have not configured AWS credentials. These are need to generate the signature. If you had used the client to send a request you would have gotten a more helpful error message indicating that credentials were required.

```
def initialize(bucket:, region:)
  @bucket = bucket
  creds = Aws::Credentials.new('ACCESS_KEY', 'SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
  client = Aws::S3::Client.new(region: region, credentials, creds)
  @signer = Aws::S3::Presigner.new(client: client)
end

def sign(key, expires_in: 3600)
  @signer.presigned_url(:get_object, bucket: @bucket, key: key, expires_in: expires_in)
end
```

Not related to your problem, but you can use the resource interface for S3 which cleans up the code a bit.

```
def initialize(bucket:, region:)
  @bucket = Aws::S3::Bucket.new(bucket, {
    region: region,
    credentials: Aws::Credentials.new('ACCESS_KEY', 'SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
  })
end

def sign(key, expires_in: 3600)
  @bucket.object(key).presigned_url(:get, expires_in: expires_in)
end
```

While I showed how to configure credentials in code, I **strongly** recommend against this. You should export credentials to ENV before launching your applications or put them in the shared credentials file.

```
$ export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...
$ export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...
```

Or put the following in ~/.aws/credentials

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id=...
aws_secret_access_key=...
```

If you use the ENV or shared credentials file, then you no longer need to configure them in code. The SDK will attempt to source these locations when they are not given to the client constructor.

Comment: In short: Aws::S3::Presigner inherits the credentials from Aws::S3::Client -- an awkward implementation -- they should have done `my_s3_client.presigner.new` instead

Comment: @Tilo I disagree. The signer is composed of a client. If a client is not provided then a default client is injected. This pre-signer then uses the client to build a http request, sign it and then it hoists authorization and other headers to the querystring of the presigned URL. The abstraction is correct. Adding a connivence method from Aws::S3::Client#presigner is sugar.