# Logstash Output Amazon ES Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, logstash

I'm using logstash 2.3.4 and Amazon Elasticsearch Service (2.3) .

My config

```
input {
jdbc {
    # Postgres jdbc connection string to our database, mydb
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://awsmigration.XXXXXXXX.ap-southeast-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/table_receipt?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"
    # The user we wish to execute our statement as
    jdbc_user => "XXXXXXXX"
    jdbc_password => "XXXXXXXX"
    # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => "/opt/logstash/drivers/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39/mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar"
    # The name of the driver class for Postgresql
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    # our query
    statement => "SELECT * from Receipt"

    jdbc_paging_enabled => true
    jdbc_page_size => 200
}
}
output {
#stdout { codec => json_lines }
amazon_es {
    hosts => ["search-XXXXXXXX.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com"]
    region => "ap-southeast-1"
    index => "slurp_receipt"
    document_type => "Receipt"
    document_id => "%{uid}"
 }
}
```

After running a command

```
bin/logstash agent -f db.conf
```

I got this error :

```
Attempted to send a bulk request to Elasticsearch configured at '["https://search-XXXXXXXX.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com:443"]', but an error occurred and it failed! Are you sure you can reach elasticsearch from this machine using the configuration provided? {:client_config=>{:hosts=>["https://search-slurp-wjgudsrlz66esh6hyrijaagamu.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com:443"], :region=>"ap-southeast-1", :aws_access_key_id=>nil, :aws_secret_access_key=>nil, :transport_options=>{:request=>{:open_timeout=>0, :timeout=>60}, :proxy=>nil}, :transport_class=>Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::HTTP::AWS, :logger=>nil, :tracer=>nil, :reload_connections=>false, :retry_on_failure=>false, :reload_on_failure=>false, :randomize_hosts=>false, :http=>{:scheme=>"https", :user=>nil, :password=>nil, :port=>443}}, :error_message=>"undefined method `credentials' for nil:NilClass", :error_class=>"NoMethodError", :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/aws-sdk-core-2.1.36/lib/aws-sdk-core/signers/v4.rb:24:in `initialize'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/local_gems/b0f0ff24/logstash-output-amazon_es-1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es/aws_v4_signer_impl.rb:36:in `signer'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/local_gems/b0f0ff24/logstash-output-amazon_es-1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es/aws_v4_signer_impl.rb:48:in `call'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/rack_builder.rb:139:in `build_response'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/faraday-0.9.2/lib/faraday/connection.rb:377:in `run_request'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/local_gems/b0f0ff24/logstash-output-amazon_es-1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es/aws_transport.rb:49:in `perform_request'", "org/jruby/RubyProc.java:281:in `call'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.18/lib/elasticsearch/transport/transport/base.rb:257:in `perform_request'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/local_gems/b0f0ff24/logstash-output-amazon_es-1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es/aws_transport.rb:45:in `perform_request'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-transport-1.0.18/lib/elasticsearch/transport/client.rb:128:in `perform_request'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/elasticsearch-api-1.0.18/lib/elasticsearch/api/actions/bulk.rb:90:in `bulk'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/local_gems/b0f0ff24/logstash-output-amazon_es-1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es/http_client.rb:53:in `bulk'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/local_gems/b0f0ff24/logstash-output-amazon_es-1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es.rb:321:in `submit'", "org/jruby/ext/thread/Mutex.java:149:in `synchronize'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/local_gems/b0f0ff24/logstash-output-amazon_es-1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es.rb:318:in `submit'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/local_gems/b0f0ff24/logstash-output-amazon_es-1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es.rb:351:in `flush'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.22/lib/stud/buffer.rb:219:in `buffer_flush'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.22/lib/stud/buffer.rb:216:in `buffer_flush'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/stud-0.0.22/lib/stud/buffer.rb:159:in `buffer_receive'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/local_gems/b0f0ff24/logstash-output-amazon_es-1.0-java/lib/logstash/outputs/amazon_es.rb:311:in `receive'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:83:in `multi_receive'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:83:in `multi_receive'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:130:in `worker_multi_receive'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:114:in `multi_receive'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:301:in `output_batch'", "org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1342:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:301:in `output_batch'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:232:in `worker_loop'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:201:in `start_workers'"], :level=>:error}
```

May i know how to solve this problems?

thank you

Comment: Looks like the same issue as this one: https://github.com/awslabs/logstash-output-amazon_es/issues/34

Comment: same issues but not solve until now

Comment: Have you tried to define your AWS credentials `aws_access_key_id` and `aws_secret_access_key`?

Comment: I'm set in Amazon Elasticsearch Service => manage access policy => allow open access to the domain .

Comment: I think the issue is not at the AWS level, but in the [`aws-sdk-core` library](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/master/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/signers/v4.rb) which expects credentials to sign the request, but can't find any.

Comment: i'm stuck with these issues more than 2 weeks , how to solve it? please teach me master

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122708/discussion-between---and-val).

Comment: See this other answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32199954/awss3presigner-undefined-method-credentials-for-nilnilclass-in-ruby I'm not sure you can get away without defining your AWS credentials. Can you try it? What does it yield?